# Get id of class and then send it to php

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, post

I would like to get the id of a class that is created in a while loop, the id of the class being the id of the user who made that post, and then send the id to php.

Basically this is what i need

HTML:

```html
<div class = 'lol' id = <?php $name ?> POST 1 </div> // id = 1
<div class = 'lol' id = <?php $name ?> Next POST </div> id = 5
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".eventer button[name=lol]").click(function() { 
    console.log('clicked'); 
    var ida = this.id;
    thisBtn = $(this); 
    parent = $(this).parent(); 
    num = parent.data('num'); 
    id = parent.data('id'); 

    if(typeof num != 'number'){ 
        num = 0; 
    } 
    $(this).attr('disabled', true); 
    $.post('javas.php', {num: (num+1), ida: ida}, function(data) {
        console.log('Ajax success'); 
        parent.next('.status').html(data); 
        thisBtn.attr('disabled', false); // reset  });

    console.log('Ajax success'); 
        parent.data('num', ++num, 'id', id); 
        parent.next('.status').html(data); 
        thisBtn.attr('disabled', false); // reset 
    });
} );
```

I am getting an undefined index error for the variable ida, please help!

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: You miss an `echo` statement in `<?php $name ?>`. Besides that, have you ever look at the HTML generated by your code? Tip: It's invalid (in a way that *will* break things)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class='lol' id='<?php $name ?>'> POST 1 </div> // id = 1
<div class='lol' id='<?php $name ?>'> Next POST </div> id = 5
```

And in your Javascript:

```
var ida = $(this).attr("id");
```

Answer (score 1):

From your comment above the code, I believe what you are after is the **index**:

```
$(".eventer button[name=lol]").each(function(index) {
    var ida = index;
    $(this).click(function() { 
        console.log('clicked'); 
        //........
    });
});
```